# Dereferencing possible null pointer with BufferedReader

Tags: java

I have this piece of code:

```
...
BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      // Do stuff...
}
reader.close();

....

BufferedReader reader2= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

while ((line = reader2.readLine()) != null) { // Here I get a "Dereferencing possible null pointer" warning!
      // Do stuff...
}
reader2.close();
...
```

If I try to execute it, I get a NullPointerException at `((line = reader2.readLine()) != null)`. The thing that I don't understand is why the declaration of the `reader2` is returning `null`. Does this have to do with the fact that I try to open two `BufferedReaders` on the same file?

Any ideas why this may be happening?

**EDIT**: The full code:

```
    BufferedReader brFileToAdjust = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileToAdjust));
    String line;
    List<String> customersToAdjust = new ArrayList<String>();
    int lineNo = 0;

    while ((line = brFileToAdjust.readLine()) != null) {

        if (lineNo != 0) { // Do not do this for the first line.:
            String[] data = line.split("\t");
            if (!customersToAdjust.contains(data[0])) {
                customersToAdjust.add(data[0]);
            }
        }
        lineNo++;
    }

    brFileToAdjust.close();
    BufferedReader brFileToAdjust2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileToAdjust));

    for (String customer : customersToAdjust) {
        boolean newCustomer = true;
        String customerTransactions[][] = new String[999][6];
        String outputCustomerTransactions[][] = new String[999][15];
        lineNo = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while ((line = brFileToAdjust2.readLine()) != null) {
              ...
        }
    }
    brFileToAdjust2.close();
```

Comment: The only way you can have a NPE on that line is if `reader2` is null. And based on your code, I can't see how that is possible.

Comment: Can you post the exact stacktrace? From the current information you gave, this is not possible. Something else has to be wrong. Also, is this an exception or an IDE warning?

Comment: There must be something missing in your example here. I have tried your example and it runs correctly on my local.

Comment: The file is not consumed, moved or deleted from the first while. The first while only contains reading all the lines of the file and changing some variables. I will update the question with the whole code to have a look.

Comment: In the while loop you only put an ellipsis...

Do you do anything to the brFileToAdjust2 inside the loop?

Comment: Still the same. Works without NPE, unless I explicitly set `brFileToAdjust2` to `null` inside the second loop (at the `...`)

Comment: @DThought I only use brFileToAdjust2 to readline().

Comment: The error does not appear if I put the `line = brFileToAdjust2.readLine();` out of the `for` loop!

Comment: do you break; inside your while loop? otherwise the while loop inside the for loop doesn't make sense at all, because it will read till EOF, and won't work for the second customer...